# Not able to connect to AWS Aurora DB server-less -- mysql engine

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I have created an AWS Aurora DB serverless publically available, and I am trying to connect to the DB using python. But I am unable to connect and I suspect the VPC.

Please suggest if I have to check anything else, also I have these below queries;

- Is AWS Aurora serverless with min configuration a free tire DB?
- My VPC while creating the DB is Public already, yet I am not able to connect so do I need to perform any additional configuration changes?

Code Snippets:

```
import mysql.connector as mysq
import sys, os, boto3 as aws, pandas as pd, pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect

ENDPOINT = "random.cluster-random.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
PORT = "3306"
USER = "random"
REGION = "ap-south-1"
DBNAME = "random"
PASSWORD = "random"
```

Method 1:

```
client = aws.client('rds')
token = client.generate_db_auth_token(DBHostname=ENDPOINT, Port=PORT, DBUsername=USER, Region=REGION)
print(token)

try:
    conn =  mysq.connect(host=ENDPOINT, user=USER, passwd=token, port=PORT, database=DBNAME)

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT now()""")
    query_results = cur.fetchall()
    print(query_results)
except Exception as e:
    print("Database connection failed due to {}".format(e))
```

Method 2:

```
CONNECTION_STRING = 'mssql+pymssql' + '://' + USER + ':' + PASSWORD + '@' + ENDPOINT + ':' + str(PORT) + '/' + DBNAME
engine = create_engine(CONNECTION_STRING)
print(inspect(engine).get_table_names())
```

Method 3:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host=ENDPOINT, user=USER,port=int(PORT), passwd=PASSWORD, db=DBNAME)
```

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: I've noticed that all almost your questions got answered yet not a single answer was [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979). Accepting useful answers is not only a good practice, but reduces duplicates and increases chances of your questions being actually answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aurora serverless **does not have public ip**. Form [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html#aurora-serverless.requirements).

> You can't give an Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster a public IP address. You can access an Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster only from within a VPC.

Same for Aurora v2.

So you have to setup a VPN between your home/work network and your VPC, or use SSH tunneling through some ec2 instance bastion host.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I will go ahead and create a SSH tunnel for the same.